# Hyper-V 2016 not merging on checkpoint delete, "Cannot locate parent virtual hard disk"

Tags: hyper-v, snapshot

This is semi-consistent behavior. I set a checkpoint on my guest VMs when I update an application, and run it for a month or so until the next one is due. At least half the time, when I right-click and delete a checkpoint, it goes faster than it should. It completely skips the merge process, and when I try to start the VM, it fails power on telling me "The chain of virtual hard disks is broken. The system cannot locate the parent virtual hard disk for the differencing disk." I've run into this behavior with guests running Debian 9, Windows 7, and Windows 10. Sometimes it works, a lot of the time it doesn't. I can't find any rhyme or reason as to when it merges or when it doesn't, but it's driving me insane. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you install the latest updates to Hyper-V 2016 (Windows updates) ? What kind of storage are you using for the VHDX ? If it's a remote storage, are you sure that the network connectivity is reliable ?

Comment: I;d try to switch to the 'Standard checkpoints' and automate merging by using GUI and PowerShell - https://trevorsullivan.net/2016/07/24/merge-hyper-v-disks/

Comment: Updates are applied monthly. Storage is local.

Comment: Archive version of the trevorsullivan DOT net link above (as it's now broken): https://web.archive.org/web/20161105015818/https://trevorsullivan.net/2016/07/24/merge-hyper-v-disks/